# How to check for boolean argument in lua function

Tags: c, lua

To get integer arguments into from the script into my C code, I can use `luaL_checknumber()`, but there is no function called `luaL_checkboolean()` that would allow me to get `bool` arguments. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can used `lua_toboolean`.

Just remember any value, in lua, other then `false` and `nil` evaluate as `true`

If necessary you can validate the value is a bool using `lua_isboolean` before `lua_toboolean`

Reference: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_toboolean